# How to re-attach LVP Stair nose piece

Tags: vinyl-flooring

One strip of LVP stair nose molding broke loose.  What is the best way to to repair? I would like to use the same piece since they may not make this style anymore.  From the photos, it looks like there was not a lot of glue on this piece and when it broke loose, it pulled some of the wood step with it. closeup

[image: LonProfileg View]

Comment: Had the same problem a couple times... That needs way more construction adhesive; 1/4 of a tube at least. You should rough up the smooth bottom of the nosing and the mating plank surface as well for better adhesion, scaring both with hatch marks from a utility knife and chisel worked for me; it should be quite rough and ugly.

Comment: Also, wipe both surfaces with plenty of isopropyl alcohol on a clean terrycloth rag before gluing, finger oils and dust prevent good adhesion.

Comment: Make an answer out of all that, @dandavis

Answer (score 0):

I would call that came loose, not Brocken off.

It came loose due to in-proper use and distribution of the glue and size of the staple nails.

Clean up the old glue by scraping. Remove the old staple nails

Apply glue in zig-zag pattern from top to bottom edge.

Use proper size staple nails.